# Laravel Telescope dump not showing on screen

Tags: php, laravel, package, dump, telescope

Dump inside of telescope not working. I am using the dump() method to dump a variable inside of telescope it is not working. I also have the telescope screen open not sure what is happening. Am I missing something?

Comment: use `dd()` for dumping.

Comment: Check the proper place of dumping variables. Make sure you are running .env on debuging

Answer (score 0):

Check the proper place of dumping variables. Sometimes if you are using error handling it ignores debugging there Or Make sure you are running .env on debugging mode.